# How to make browser custom styles (Chrome) work on Google Earth Web?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-earth

I am using **Chrome** browser, version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit). And I use **Stylus** extension for custom styles on some websites, for specific reasons.

I want to hide certain interface elements on https://earth.google.com/web/. For example, **div id="earthNavigationElements"**. Currently, I am doing this manually every time I visit Google Earth, by right clicking on the elements, Inspect and then delete element from HTML.

For any other website, Stylus works fine, I simply have `#div-id { display:none }` for the respective elements. But it has no effect on Google Earth Web. Seems like Google has some kind of protection.

I tried Firefox + Stylus too, and it doesn't work on there too.

Any ideas how to apply custom styles on Google Earth Web, with or without an extension, so that I don't have to manually hide certain interface elements every time?

Comment: They probably use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of that the element you want to hide is inside of the `shadow-root` so you can't apply CSS to that elements easily.

I have this JavaScript code which helps you to solve your problem:

```
var earthElements = document.querySelectorAll('earth-app');
earthElements.forEach(function(item){
  var root = item.shadowRoot;
  root.querySelector('#earthNavigationElements').style.display = 'none';
})
```

Comment: How do I use the above code? Where do I put it?

Comment: you can put it in <script>`script code here`</script> before </body>

Comment: Which `<body>` are you referring to? I am viewing https://earth.google.com/web/ in Chrome browser. I am not building a web page.